# Ubuntu 13.10 and Lenovo video card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, video, lenovo

i have a old Lenovo Y510.
i was running Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 
it ran very well in either windows or Ubuntu 12.04 but i never could find the drivers for the video card more specifically the s-video TV out wont work ... i use this old faithful Laptop for a Media Center it plays movies and music quite well i still use it for work from time to time and it does well.
point being i like this laptop we have been though hell together. i had hoped Ubuntu 13.10 would have more updated drivers for that.. i have to run Windows to connect this to my old TV via the s-video output. i would rather use Ubuntu for all that. any clues? or am i stuck using Windows 7 or do i have to invest in a new TV with VGA inputs?
 was hoping to retire this computer to my entertainment center and let her live out her days that way as i have Much Newer more powerful computers i use for my work.
Please if anyone has any INFO help me keep my old friend in service.
FYI she is running 4 GIGs RAM and a core 2 Duo, 1 TB Hybrid Hard-drive. very fast for her age.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this guide to solve it on my old desktop computer back in the day. You could try it out. The feature is switched OFF by default because it's not working very well.

At least give it a try.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/SVideo

Edit: Using desktop effects is not recomended though, and last time I used it I was using Gnome 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Actually chances are better if you tried an *older* version of Ubuntu (or at least of the kernel). Newer versions seem to play worse with my oldish Lenovo ThinkPad T61 (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/400044/nvidia-x-server-flickers-hangs-and-segfaults-on-start-up).